# Docker update error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, docker

My getting this error during the Jenkins update.

```
Creating config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades with new version
stat: cannot statx '/usr/share/unattended-upgrades/20auto-upgrades': Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 installed unattended-upgrades package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.96.20.2-2.1) ...
Setting up software-properties-common (0.96.20.2-2.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unattended-upgrades
[91mE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You can try this : https://www.tecmint.com/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-in-ubuntu/